# Python - Display rows with repeated values in csv files

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a .csv file with several columns, one of them filled with random numbers and I want to find duplicated values there. In case there are - strange case, but it's what I want to check after all -, I would like to display/store the complete row in which those values are stored.

To make it clear, I have sth like this:

> First, Whatever, 230, Whichever, etc
>    Second, Whatever, 11, Whichever, etc
>    Third, Whatever, 46, Whichever, etc
>    Fourth, Whatever, 18, Whichever, etc
>    Fifth, Whatever, 14, Whichever, etc
>    Sixth, Whatever, 48, Whichever, etc
>    Seventh, Whatever, 91, Whichever, etc
>    Eighth, Whatever, 18, Whichever, etc
>    Ninth, Whatever, 67, Whichever, etc

And I would like to have:

> Fourth, Whatever, 18, Whichever, etc
>    Eighth, Whatever, 18, Whichever, etc

To find duplicated values, I store that column into a dictionary and I count every key in order to discover how many times they appear.

```
import csv
from collections import Counter, defaultdict, OrderedDict

with open(file, 'rt') as inputfile:
        data = csv.reader(inputfile)

        seen = defaultdict(set)
        counts = Counter(row[col_2] for row in data)

print "Numbers and times they appear: %s" % counts
```

And I see

> Counter({' 18 ': 2, ' 46 ': 1, ' 67 ': 1, ' 48 ': 1,...})

The problem comes now because I don't manage to link the key with the repetitions and compute it later. If I do

```
for value in counts:
        if counts > 1:
            print counts
```

I would be taking only the key, which is not what I want and every value (not to mention that I'm looking to print not only that but the whole line...)

Basically I'm looking for a way of doing

```
If there's a repeated number:
        print rows containing those number
else
        print "No repetitions"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it fine an answer in awk? It is pretty straight-forward.

Comment: Yup... as you want. I have no background at all in AWK, but as Python is a multiparadigm language maybe the solution could be adapted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this  may work for you.

```
entries = []
duplicate_entries = []
with open('in.txt', 'r') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        columns = line.strip().split(',')
        if columns[2] not in entries:
            entries.append(columns[2])
        else:
            duplicate_entries.append(columns[2]) 

if len(duplicate_entries) > 0:
    with open('out.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        with open('in.txt', 'r') as my_file:
            for line in my_file:
                columns = line.strip().split(',')
                if columns[2] in duplicate_entries:
                    print line.strip()
                    out_file.write(line)
else:
    print "No repetitions"
```

Comment: It does exactly what I'm asking. Thanks!

Comment: If your file is long, you could avoid re-reading the file by saving both the key (columns[2]) and the complete line as a tuple or a dict in duplicate_entries.

Comment: @joelgoldstick in that case you will miss the first occurrence in every duplicate entry

Comment: Sorry @Sar009, but how should I do to store repetitions into a file instead of printing them? I am unable to write more than one line into one (or overwriting each and every of them, possibly). Thanks in advance. –

Answer (score 1):

You should create your dictionary like the following so duplicate entries don't overwrite eachother:

```
if(dict.has_key(num) == 0):
     dict[num] = []
     dict[num].append(val)
else:
     dict[num].append(val)
```

Then loop through each list value in the dictionary, if the value for a certain key is greater than 1, then it appears more than once.

Comment: But I'm already doing that with my piece of code. My problem comes in the loop you mention, as I didn't know how to link at the same time the key with the number of times it appears.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just loop through the file twice:

- first keep track of how many times each single 3rd column is appearing.
- second loop through lines printing those containing a 3rd column that appeared more than once.

See:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$3]++; next}
         {if (a[$3]>1) {print}}' file file
```

#### Test

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$3]++; next} {if (a[$3]>1) {print}}' a a
Fourth, Whatever, 18, Whichever, etc
Eighth, Whatever, 18, Whichever, etc
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply get the duplicates lines with `pandas`:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv(csv_file, names=fields, index_col=False)
df = df[df.duplicated([column_name], keep=False)]
df.to_csv(csv_file2, index=False)
```