# Tools or python libraries to detect records duplicate

Tags: python

I’m trying to find duplicates in a single csv file by python so through my search I found dedupe.io which is a platform using python and machine learning algorithms to detect records duplicate but it’s not a free tool. However, I don’t want to use the traditional method which the compared columns should specified. I would like to find a way to detect duplicate with a high accuracy. Therefore, is there any tool or python library to find duplicates for text datasets?

- Here is an example which could clarify that:

  ```
    Title, Authors, Venue, Year
    1- Clustering validity checking methods: part II, Maria Halkidi, Yannis Batistakis, Michalis Vazirgiannis, ACM SIGMOD Record, 2002
    2- Cluster validity methods: part I, Yannis Batistakis, Michalis Vazirgiannis, ACM SIGMOD Record, 2002
    3- Book reviews, Karl Aberer, ACM SIGMOD Record, 2003
    4- Book review column, Karl Aberer, ACM SIGMOD Record, 2003
    5- Book reviews, Leonid Libkin, ACM SIGMOD Record, 2003
  ```

So, we can decide that records 1 and 2 are not duplicate even though they are contain almost similar data but slightly different in the Title column. Records 3 and 4 are duplicate but record 5 is not referring to the same entity.

Comment: give a short example of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: use `pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates()`
[documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-across-multiple-columns-in-python-pandas)

Comment: Please give more details about the task you try to achieve, are you trying to find exact duplicates or doing record linkage?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Display rows with repeated values in csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24698217/python-display-rows-with-repeated-values-in-csv-files) ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095523/script-to-find-duplicates-in-a-csv-file ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386356/finding-total-number-of-duplicates-in-csv-file?rq=1 ; Did you try any of those?

Comment: @A Co
it is record linkage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Pandas` provides provides a very straightforward way to achieve this [pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

Given the following file (`data.csv`) stored in the current working directory.

```
name,age,salary
John Doe,25,50000
Jayne Doe,20,80000
Tim Smith,40,100000
John Doe,25,50000
Louise Jones,25,50000
```

The following script can be used to remove duplicate records, writing the processed data to a csv file in the current working directory (`processed_data.csv`).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df.to_csv("processed_data.csv", index=False)
```

The resultant output in this example looks like:

```
name,age,salary
John Doe,25,50000
Jayne Doe,20,80000
Tim Smith,40,100000
Louise Jones,25,50000
```

[pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) also allows dropping of duplicate attributes from a specific column (instead of just duplicates of entire rows), column names are specified using the `subset` argument.

e.g

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["age"])
df.to_csv("processed_data.csv", index=False)
```

Will remove all duplicate values from the `age` column, maintaining only the first record containing a value duplicated in the `age` field of later records.

In this example case the output would be:

```
name,age,salary
John Doe,25,50000
Jayne Doe,20,80000
Tim Smith,40,100000
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @JPI93 for your answer but some duplicate still exist and didn't removed. I think this method works for the exact duplicate; if this is the case, it's not what i'm looking for. I want to apply record linkage which identify the records that refer to the same entity and then can be removed.

Comment: If you want to drop duplicates based on a specific column value (instead of just entire row matches) you can pass the column name(s) to be checked by passing the `subset` kwarg to `drop_duplicates()` - [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)